# Laravel 5.5 Queues & Jobs : job is never executed

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs, lumen

I'm fairly new to Lumen (Laravel), and I'm currently digging the concept of Queues, Jobs & Scheduled Tasks.

I would like to store in a Queue some Eloquent models, when I receive them from API calls. Then, I want to create a scheduled task which runs a daily Job, to fetch all those models in Queue and then send a report email.

I went the database storing way for Queues.
So I added the `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` key in my .env file and my queue.php config file looks like this :

```
<?php

return [
    'database' => [
        'connection' => 'my_db_connection',
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90
    ]
];
```

I ran the `php artisan queue:table` command to create the migration file and ran migration to create my table. I have a table jobs, with the right intended fields.

I created a class, implementing ShouldQueue :

```
class ProcessDeliveryOrders implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $deliveryOrder;

    public function __construct($deliveryOrder)
    {
        $this->deliveryOrder = $deliveryOrder;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
      // $this->deliveryOrder->save(); ?
    }
}
```

**As sub-question here is about how this class is working** : Can it stores automatically the Eloquent model when it receives it in it's constructor ? to me the handle method is called when the object is retrieved by the Job, but I can be wrong and it's used to store the object ?

Then, I created a MailingJob : it's goal is to aggregate all the ProcessDeliveryOrders stored daily, and create an email from them :

```
class SendDeliveryEmailJob extends Job
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle()
    {
         // DeliveryOrder is my Eloquent Model
        $deliveryOrders = DeliveryOrder::query()
            ->whereBetween('createdAt', [strtotime('today midnight'), strtotime('today midnight')])
            ->get();

        $mail = Mail::to(config('admin.emails'));
        $mail->send(
            new DeliveryOrderReportMailTemplate([
                'deliveryOrders' => $deliveryOrders
            ])
        );
    }
}
```

And in my Kernel.php, I have added the following line in function schedule() :

```
   // everyMinute for test purposes only
   $schedule->job(new SendDeliveryEmailJob())->everyMinute();
```

As I'm using Lumen, I don't have the exact same process as in pure Laravel, so when I receive a delivery order to call my dispatch, I tried both ways exposed by the Lumen doc (forced to create an instance of my Job) :

```
dispatch(new ProcessDeliveryOrders($deliveryOrder));
// OR
Queue::push(new ProcessDeliveryOrders($deliveryOrder));
```

After all this setup, I tried few commands like `php artisan queue:listen` or `php artisan queue:work`, and the command line seems to be stuck.

If I run `php artisan queue:listen database` I get the following looped error :

> In QueueManager.php line 172:
>
> No connector for []

I checked documentation twice, and tried the new key `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` instead of `QUEUE_DRIVER` but it's apparently only since 5.7, and didn't worked either. Any chance you spot something I'm missing ? Thanks a lot

**EDIT**: When I put a logging in the SendDeliveryEmailJob constructor, and I `run php artisan queue:listen`, I see the echo output every 2 or 3 seconds. I've also put a log into the handle function but I never see this one called.

**EDIT 2**: I noticed that when I try to execute my scheduled tasks with `php artisan scheduled:run`, it throws an error :

```
Running scheduled command: App\Jobs\SendDeliveryEmailJob
    In Schedule.php line 87:

      Call to a member function onQueue() on null
```

I guess from this message, that my Job is not instanciated, but I see the constructor message displayed to it's kinda weird..

Answer (score 0):

@alex `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` put this in your env and your queue.php is

```
'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],
```

Comment: `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` not `QUEUE_DRIVER` @Alex

Comment: > checked documentation twice, and tried the new key QUEUE_CONNECTION=database instead of QUEUE_DRIVER but it's apparently only since 5.7, and didn't worked either.
Currently my version of Lumen (and Laravel) is 5.5 so the key property is QUEUE_DRIVER ;) But anyway I think my issue is related to a bug in Lumen 5.5 with Queues so I began to migrate to Lumen 5.8.